# environment variables for dynamic selection of databases

Tags: php, mysql

How could I manage to change databases according to the user. Say I have users in all over the US. When they sign in I want to be able to separate my database by states. I know I can easily change the database when I open the connection. But I have read that credentials (database info in this case) should be put in a safe place (i.e., not in the code). Where and how can I accomplish this in a shared host. I initially thought of a .env folder but I don't even know where to start with this!

Comment: Im confused with your term `user`? Your need a place to store the user login auth so in a database like normal, then based upon their location switch to another db, though why are you doing this? And not perhaps just replicating the application across subdomains or /path to upstream? Or just one database, if your on a shared host it really doesn't matter.

Comment: you usually would not have separate databases, but distinguish states within one db. but if you really need to you can put the db name in the query. `select * from state.xxxx` etc state being a variable

Comment: No, I need to be able to choose a database based on the user signing in.

Comment: Well, if databases grow fast they can get really big and therefore making them slower!

Comment: a properly set up database will find the value you are looking for at the same speed if it has 10 or 10 million rows.

Comment: Like I said your need a central place for users to sign in, otherwise where are you going to store user->state data? And if your checking by IP when they go on holiday or in another state, they won't be able to login :/ databases can grow to *really big* without issues.

Comment: Besides if your expecting millions of users, then shared hosting will be the problem not a database connection.

Comment: What are you going to do when a user moves from Idaho to Hawaii ?

Answer (score 1):

In one app I managed, the credentials-per-database were kept in the database! So the app had to have a sort of "master" credential to connect first to one central database, so it could find out what it should use for the respective user. The master credential for that app was kept in a Java properties file. This was for a Java app.

Something similar can be done with any language. For example, PHP has .ini files, which you would store alongside your PHP app, but outside the HTML doc root. Load them with [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

It might seem like a lot of work to connect to the database twice on every request for a PHP app (Java mitigates this by maintaining connection pools that exist for hours or days). If so, you could cache the credentials in a key/value store like memcached.

So the pseudocode/logic would be:

1. App initializes to handle a request
2. Determine the user from the SESSION, or the URL, or whatever
3. Check memcached to see if the MySQL credentials & database are in the cache
4. If not found in cache:

   a. Open the ini file and parses it to get the master credential. The location of the ini file may be hard-coded or else in the environment.

   b. Connect to user credential database and read credentials & database for the respective app user

   c. Store credentials & database in the cache so the next request can find them quickly
5. Either way, now the App is ready to connect to the correct user database

Answer (score -3):

I'm not discussing the pro and contra of multi-database-connections per user.

What you could think of is a master database, where everyone connects to at first. Here, you define an additional table for database servers (note: they must be reachable from the webfrontend, that connects to it!) and another table for user2database relation.

On a side note: "should be put in a safe place" means more that you don't have a file with credentials lying around in an space that is reachable from the internet. 
In fact it is status quo to have this info somewhere in a code file, but outside of the webroot. Having it in code has the advantage, that even if it was reachable through the web, someone calling the script will only see its output, not the source code. In opposite, a text file would be served "as-is"...